# Fatal EXCEPTION:main , kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to implement uploading images and videos to firebase. I used two methods called `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to save variables. It works! ..but when activity gets rotation it gives error like below

[Logcat Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBErr.png)

Here is my code:

```
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
storageReference = storage?.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://mypublicservice-98437.appspot.com/complain_images/")
storageReference2 = storage?.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://mypublicservice-98437.appspot.com/complain_videos/")

var pDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
pDialog.setTitle("Uploading...")
pDialog.setCancelable(true)
pDialog.show()
val childref = storageReference2?.child(videouri!!.lastPathSegment)
val childref2 = storageReference?.child(fp!!.lastPathSegment) // this is line 194
val uploadTask = childref?.putFile(videouri!!)
val uploadTask2 = childref2?.putFile(fp!!)

uploadTask2?.addOnSuccessListener {
    uploadTask?.addOnSuccessListener {

    }
    pDialog.dismiss()
    var builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ComplainActivity)
    builder.setTitle("Complain has been submitted !")
        /* .setPositiveButton("ok"){dialog, id:Int->
         finish()
     }*/
        .setNeutralButton("ok") { dialog, which ->

        }
        .create().show()
}
```

[image: image of a larger piece of code]

Comment: `fp` is null on line 194?

Comment: No .. fp is not null

Comment: Fp is nothing but .. imageuri

Comment: Possibly because you used `!!` for something that is actually null

Comment: We don't know where `videouri` is coming from, how should we tell you how to fix this? :O

Comment: what is the value of `fp` at the time of crash?

Comment: @Droidman yup i got problem ... fp value gets null while activity gets landscape or portrait mode ..

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use assertion operator(!!). This is the biggest reason for the error. Instead, you can use the safe call operator(?) or Elvis operator (?:).

I think, you need to more information for Kotlin Null Safety. You can visit this site [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).